# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1- \sqrt[n]{n})^n$ converge absolutely?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I want to determine if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1- \sqrt[n]{n})^n$ converges absolutely or conditionally.

Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1- \sqrt[n]{n})=0<1$ so the sequence converges.

Now I need to find it for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|(1- \sqrt[n]{n})^n|$, but I don't know what I should do.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just apply the same root-test to the absolute values?

Comment: @WillM. I tried, but how?

Comment: $|t^n| = |t|^n.$

Comment: @WillM. I think that I will need to prove it. Thanks!

Comment: The root test is supposed to be applied with absolute values in the first place; you don't need to prove it. Otherwise you will get nonsense values taking the even roots of negative numbers (doesn't happen here because of special reasons but in general it does).

Answer (score 2):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\left|\left(1-\sqrt[n]n\right)^n\right|=\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)^n.$$Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n-1=0<1,$$the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\left(1-\sqrt[n]n\right)^n\right|$ converges; in other words, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\sqrt[n]n\right)^n$ is absolutely convergent.